# How execute code before which the Inno Select language dialog is shown

Tags: inno-setup

I need to execute a pascal code before that the Select Setup language Dialog is shown , unfortunately the  *InitializeSetup* event is executed after.

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean; //This event occurs to late
begin
    DoSomething(); 
    Result := True;
end;
```

So it's possible execute a script code before of the Select Setup language Dialog is shown?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, and I thought about different workarounds: style all setup manually, or make inner localization, but they all looked so doomed from the beginning.
[Select Setup language Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702064/select-setup-language-dialog)

I have forked issrc, built it locally, and looked at the main.pas of the Setup project. I see the idea behind doing as it is now : people may wanna use `{Language}` in `InitializeSetup`, so its called after the `AskForLanguage` method.

To just check the idea I made small changes to main.pas: call `AskForLanguage` after `CodeRunner` inited and `InitializeSetup` called. I got VCL'ed Select Setup Language dialog, but not all - NON Client Area wasnt VCL'ed:

[image]

I've tried to inherit the language form not from the `TForm` class but from the `TSetupForm`, or call it in the middle of setup or make other changes - with no result. If anybody know why it's not VCL'ed - tell me please!

Then I read the [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article and just made the form border `bsNone` and got this:

[image]

So for now I'm fine with it. That form not styled before many pages of styled setup was so... annoying.

If we wanna do it a right way, I guess all that needs to be done - is moving `CodeRunner` init before `AskForLanguage`, and add a custom code function like `StyleInit` or so. Then all will be happy: `{Language}` will be available in `InitializeSetup` and Dialog will be VCL'ed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the function InitializeSetup() is called as first.
All other functions are called later.

Of course you can modify Inno's sources and add custom functions but I think it is not your case.

Why do you need this? Maybe there is solution which can solve your situation, please tell us details.

Comment: I had a plugin for skin the inno setup installation, the skin is initialized in the InitializeSetup event, so the Select Setup language Dialog is not skined.

Comment: Hmmm, then try to add custom event directly into Inno's sources. You cannot achieve this without modifying sources.

Comment: @Slappy, that needs more than this. You'll have to move this dialog creation after the Pascal Script runner will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is using Inno setup Ultra, it has several inprovements, and InitializeLanguageDialog function is one of them. just load style in it. (Also you can freely change language dialog itself that is so nice).

Comment: Is that open source ? If not, I wouldn't use it. You know, installers are a very good tool to spread virus infections...

Comment: http://restools.hanzify.org/ - its chinese company ResTools, they work for chinese game publishers, and make chinese versions of games. You can check result with antivirus I guess?
Maybe somewhere there is a source, but I dont know chinese at all - so couldnt find anything )